# Adding items to list from DataRow

Tags: c#, list, datarow

I have following code to copy DataTable rows into my Object. But it overwrites previously added list items each time with the new row. What is wrong with my code?

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableByIndex(data, 1);
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      providerQualification.ProviderDetails = new List<ProviderDetail>();
      ProviderDetail providerDetail = new ProviderDetail();
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          providerDetail.ProviderName = row["Provider Name"].ToString();
          providerDetail.QualificationTime = row["Qualify Time (Sec.)"].ToString();
          providerDetail.ServiceableOffers = row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString();
          providerQualification.ProviderDetails.Add(providerDetail);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mark my answer as "Answer" if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableByIndex(data, 1);
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      providerQualification.ProviderDetails = new List<ProviderDetail>();
      ProviderDetail providerDetail;
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {    
          providerDetail = new ProviderDetail();
          providerDetail.ProviderName = row["Provider Name"].ToString();
          providerDetail.QualificationTime = row["Qualify Time (Sec.)"].ToString();
          providerDetail.ServiceableOffers = row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString();
          providerQualification.ProviderDetails.Add(providerDetail);
      }
  }
```